# Rails Scope count record by day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app where I use a dashboard to give basic statistics such as call counts for the day and such.  I have multiple scopes which count the calls for today, year to date, and previous year to date.  I'd like to add a way to count calls by day of the week M, T, W, Th, Fri, Sat, Sun of the current week.

So far I wrote a simple scope that passes a date argument and queries for `transfer_date` as follows:

**call.rb**

```
scope :by_day,  lambda { |date| where('transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day) }
```

So if I do: `Call.by_day(1.day.ago)` I get an array of all calls from yesterday within that 24 hour period.

In my view I could simply do `@call.by_day(1.day.ago).count @call.by_day(2.day.ago).count` etc.  But I'd like to constrain the numbers of the current week, otherwise it's a 7 day running count.  I guess above each output I could do `<%= 1.day.ago.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %> <%= 2.day.ago.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>` etc.  But this doesn't seem very clean.

So to summarize I'd like to get a snapshot of the week, counts by day of the week, each with a day label (mon, tue, etc) or a date label (9/22/14, 9/23/14), etc.

Does anyone have any advice on how to cleanly do this and also minimize queries on view load?

Answer (score 0):

I have a gem for this called [by_star](https://github.com/radar/by_star).

Here's some examples from the README:

```
Post.by_year(2013)                           # all posts in 2013
Post.before(Date.today)                      # all posts for before today
Post.yesterday                               # all posts in 2013
Post.between_times(Time.zone.now - 3.hours,  # all posts in last 3 hours
                  Time.zone.now)
@post.next                                   # next post after a given post
```

To get posts by a day,

```
Post.by_day(1.day.ago)
```

Comment: This is really cool, I like it.  The only caveat is I'm trying to get a count of my `Call` model based on a column called `transfer_date` not by `created_at`.  Is there a way to pass the `transfer_date` as an argument to get a count based off of that?  We do statistics based off of `transfer_date` since we want to know what calls landed on what date.  So for instance the call may have been created today but the `transfer_date` might be tomorrow.  So calling `Call.today.count` using your gem might give skewed numbers in our scenario.  Thoughts?

Comment: Awesome, I'll load up the gem and give it a try.  I'll have to get rid of my `today` scope that I use to count the calls if I use this gem, but no big deal.